# Using key and values in collections

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way to make a key for searching the values in the collections and not returning null keys and values?

Comment: @Johanna, it seems like you're asking an awful lot of very brief, very hard-to-understand questions. I'd strongly recommend taking a few minutes to describe in greater detail what it is you're really trying to do, rather than just throwing out a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement your own [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which throws for example `IllegalArgumentException` instead of returning `null`.

All with all, this makes no sense. If you want, just test the existence of the key using `Map#containsKey()` and/or check if the returned value is `null` or not.